# Calculation operation of Filtered Inventory Data

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the program for calculation of Date Diff. between a cell and a column, and then a small calculation with in column and then Filtering  Inventory till a particular date (It is the same Date used for calculating the Date. Diff. in first line of the programm. In the programm, I am not getting the result of the calculation operation. I get only 0 as answer only one cell. Can some one help to identify the problem.

```
Sub Filter_RPCALC()

'Calculation of Date Diff.
Range("N2").Formula = "=DAYS($A$590,D2)"
Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N585"), Type:=xlFillDefault

'Calculation of Rp
Dim Rp As Integer
Dim var1 As Integer
Dim var2 As Integer
Dim var3 As Integer
var1 = Range("M2:M585").Select
var2 = Range("02:0585").Select
var3 = Range("L2:L585").Select
Rp = var1 * var2 + var3
Range("P2:P585").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Rp

'Filter the coils for Deliver Date
ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$585").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(Range("A590"))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use `Select`. Try this instead:

```
Sub Filter_RPCALC()

Dim was As Worksheet

'Calculation of Date Diff.
Range("N2").Formula = "=DAYS($A$590,D2)"
Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N585"), Type:=xlFillDefault

'Calculation of Rp
Dim var1 As Variant, var2 As Variant, var3 As Variant
Dim Rp As Variant
Dim i As Long
var1 = Range("M2:M585").Value
var2 = Range("02:0585").Value
var3 = Range("L2:L585").Value
Rp = var1
For i = LBound(Rp,1) To UBound(Rp,1)
    Rp(i,1) = var1(i,1)*var2(i,1) + var3(i,1)
Next i
Range("P2:P585").Value = Rp

'Filter the coils for Deliver Date
ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$585").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(Range("A590"))

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

ActiveSheet.Range("G1:G585").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: with this I am getting a  Compile error - Duplicate Declaration  in Current Scope'    at line 'Dim Rp As Variant'

Comment: Yeah sorry scratch the first `Dim Rp As Integer`

Comment: Works..! Thanks a lot marco. :)

Comment: is it possible to include a line program to move the First 10 Highest values of Column P in the filtered data (rows) to a new sheet..? I had done using check box macros before. But I want to put a condition that, it will move the First 10 or 7 or 2 Highest values to a new sheet

Comment: @sheela the edited version should move the filtered Data to a new Worksheet. Now you want to only copy the highest x values? Where would you define the criteria?

Comment: That will be displayed in a cell against each delivery Date. See Example:                                                                              17.03.2017 10
20.03.2017 2
21.03.2017 21
23.03.2017 4                                                                                                                  That is for each delivery date, the products with highest values in required quantity has to be moved to new sheet. I mean the complete row of that cell has to be moved. to sheet2. In sheet 2 already, the same titles will be present.

Comment: Hallo marco. why did you declare in this Program - Rp = var1. You have already declared var1 = Range("M2:M585").Value. I didnt get this point. I am getting wrong values finally

Comment: Just to make them have the same Dimension. Try deleting thst line and running it again